# Python webapp dynamic paths

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm currently experimenting with some APIs, and I'll like to know how to use URLs as a parameter for an app. For example:

http://www.myapp.com/myapp/jack 
prints out "hello jack"

or

http://www.myapp.com/myapp/john 
prints out "hello john"

or http://www.myapp.com/myapp/john%20jack prints out "hello john jack"

I'd like some pointers on where I can look for this functionality. I have a feeling this is easy but I just can't grasp it. Is it dependent on the framework I'm using? I'm very new to Python so I'm still coming to terms with Django and the likes. I'm using Python on Google App Engine with GAE's bundled webapp framework.

This is currently the code I'm working with right now:

```
import cgi

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self,url=None):
    self.response.out.write("hello " + str(url))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                    (r'/(\w+)', MainPage)
                                    ],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: I think you should start with getting started tutorial for [Python 2.5](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/) or [Python2.7](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/) first. It will introduce webapp framework to you and some App Engine concepts.

Comment: i've already gone through the tutorial for Python 2.5, but generally I'm still confused. I do know how to map specific URLs, but not when it's dynamic. I've managed to figure out the key line is `application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/(\w+)', RequestHandler)]`. Now I'm checking out the regex for when I want to include %20.

Comment: ah, after you edited your question it is more clear what you want to achieve. `/myapp/(.*)` regex matches any sequence of characters after `/myapp/` part of URL. So now try to place it into an appropriate part of your code... ;)

Comment: Alright I got it working! To get "jack john" from "jack%20john" I used the str.replace() method. That's the most efficient method right? Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wei,

You have to create a url pattern like when you get the request at `myapp` you will parse the remaining url and display the message.

for example

File `helloworld/app.yaml`

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

File `helloworld/helloworld.py`

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, url=None):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Happy New Year '+str(url))

#application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
#                                     [('/', MainPage)],
#                                     debug=True)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                    (r'/myapp/(?P<url>\d{4})/$', MainPage)
                                    ],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So this will handle all you request at `/myapp/year/` so from this you have to get the value after `/myapp/` and display the year.

**Note: Do for long url your self so you will get the idea how will it works :).**

Comment: i'm still trying to figure it out. I've looked at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) but I can't figure out where to put the code for the patterns, because I keep getting ImportError. I'm already using the code you posted above. Is there something I need to add or edit? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just curious, is the `?P<url>` tag really needed?

I managed to solve the problem by just using

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                    (r'/myapp(/.*)*?', MainPage)
                                    ],
                                     debug=True)
```

Thanks Lafada & Wei Hao for sharing with us. I was stuck at this problem as well and I found this discussion really helpful :)

Comment: Hi Antoni! Haha seems like lots of us were stuck on this question. Well for me what worked was `r'/(.*)'`, you don't even need the `*?` behind the brackets. Also, my initial solution `r'/(\w+)'` wasn't foolproof as it only managed to capture the first word in the path.